# Move the output message "On stock" beneath the add to cart button

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress with woocommerce and trying to set up some variable products. But variable products show the "In Stock" messages directly below the input/select field. I want it to be shown below the "Add to cart" button. 
I am using a child theme for the files, simple.php, variable.php and variation.php.

Feel free to look at the picture to see what I want to do.
http://art-wood.de/instock-move.png

Currently my variable.php looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Variable product add to cart 
*
* This template can be overridden by copying it to                     yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php.
*
* HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files        and you (the theme developer).
* will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
* as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
* be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
*
* @see  http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
* @author  WooThemes
* @package WooCommerce/Templates
* @version 2.5.0
*/
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

global $product;

$attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post"     enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id   ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !==  $available_variations ) : ?>
<div class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></div>
<?php else : ?>
<span class="variations" cellspacing="0">

<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>

<label class="label" for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name );  ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label>
<div class="value">
<?php
$selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title(       $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute(  $attribute_name );
wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options,   'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' =>  $selected ) );
echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? apply_filters(   'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations"  href="#">'  . __( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
                    ?>
</div>

<?php endforeach;?>

</span>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

<div class="single_variation_wrap">
/**
* woocommerce_before_single_variation Hook.
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

/**
* woocommerce_single_variation hook. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
* @since 2.4.0
* @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
* @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );

/**
* woocommerce_after_single_variation Hook.
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

Does somebody know how to move the message down below the Add to cart button? This would be amazing! May its a simple add to the functions.php maybe its a switch in the variable.php... I don't know that. Otherwise I wouldn't ask :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by myself. Maybe its useful for someone so here it is ;)
Simply add this to your functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' , 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 20 );
```